# Browser refresh(F5) error in ember.js

Tags: browser, ember.js, refresh

My work: Rails4 + Ember.js(1.0.0).

Problem:

When i `linkTo` '#/posts/1' from '#/posts', it's ok.

But then, if i refresh(F5) in '#/posts/1' route, browser will load '#/posts' route and not '#/posts/1' which is i want.

Why? Any reasons?

In router.js.coffee:

```
App.Router.map ()->
  @resource 'posts', ()->
    @route 'new'
    @route 'edit', {path: '/:post_id'}
```

routes:

```
App.PostsEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: (params)->
    return App.Post.find(params.post_id)
})
```

controller:

```
App.PostsEditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    update: ()->
      // $('button[name=update]').find('.btn-load').addClass('active')
      @get('content.transaction').commit()
  }
})
```

Thanks and HappyNewYear,

#### Updated

@kingpin2k

```
DAtrs.Store = DS.Store.extend
  revision: 13,
  adapter: 'DS.RESTAdapter'
```

, and

```
gem 'ember-rails'
gem 'ember-source', '1.0.0'
gem 'handlebars_assets', '~> 0.14.1'
gem 'emblem-rails'
```

---

@steve-h

Yes! In theory u're right.

**I changed 'edit' to 'post'**

I tested with `console.log` in `PostIndexRoute`. 
it was not called in before, but ur answer `@resource`.

Thanks!

However, the refresh problem is still existed.

And, it generated a new problem. when i `linkTo` the route `/posts/:post_id`, it does not show information, but before.(ur answer explained it)

Because and then, i saw console in browswer. it took a request of '/posts.json', not '/posts/1.json'. Why?

what's your understanding of ember-data and DS.RESTAdapter.

routes:

```
App.PostIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: (params)->
    console.log '...PostIndexRoute......'
    return App.Post.find(params.post_id)
})
```

i confirmed '/posts/1.json' and it worked :

```
{
  "post": {
    "title": "Hello World",
    "id": 1
  }
}
```

Sorry and Thanks!

#### Updated-2

> Because and then, i saw console in browswer. it took a request of '/posts.json', not '/posts/1.json'. Why?

Means:

when i `linkTo` the route `/posts/:post_id`, it does not show information.

but in console:

```
...PostIndexRoute......
XHR finished loading: "/posts".
```

i don't know why it does not "/posts/1"?

and when i refresh browser this time, it will redirect to '/#/posts'.

Comment: Will you please add the rest of your routes, nothing  here would cause this.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this part: " it took a request of '/posts.json', not '/posts/1.json'. Why?"  What URL were you trying to go to when you saw those requests?

Answer (score 0):

Your router setup seems to be the problem.  try:

```
App.Router.map ()->
  @resource 'posts', ()->
    @route 'new'
    @resource 'edit', {path: '/:post_id'}
```

When you `{{link-to}}`, you are passing the model object directly and the `model:` function on the route is not called.  When you refresh, you are reconstructing the model given the id.  Specifying `resource` for the edit path will make Ember use your `PostsEditRoute`.